# I'm new to php I'm getting this error "PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sum' (T_VARIABLE)"

Tags: php, syntax-error, parse-error, php-parse-error

**This is the code**

```
<?php


$sum=1+1;
$sub=1-1;
$div=1/1;
$mult=1*1;
printf("SUM:%d\nSUB:%d\nDIV:%d\nMULTI:%d\n",$sum,$sub,$div,$mult);

?>
```

**ERROR:**

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$sum' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/labsstorage/home/Jaswanth/files/test.php on line 40

Comment: [`Not reproducible`](https://onecompiler.com/php/3xpqwbyz3) Maybe you are missing a semicolon or comma or any braces above the sum declaration.

Comment: @nice_dev but see did i missed any semicolon ,comma or braces !!

Comment: If you actually haven't, then how are you getting this error? Did you see my attached link in the previous comment? The code you showed in your question doesn't produce any error on our end.

Comment: The code as presented compiles and runs successfully. **It also does not have 40 lines.** Check it again, something doesn't match up.

Comment: yes now it's working properly thanks :)  @nice_dev

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

`echo "SUM:".$sum."SUB:".$sub."DIV:".$div."MULTI:".$mult;`

Comment: I highly doubt this will solve the OP's problem, as the use of the "printf" is probably a requirement of the homework.